# How to make Windows Media Player play only audio of video files - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, video, windows-media-player

Usually, for any video file, Windows Media Player plays video along with audio, unless user press mute, so that only video comes out. In such a way reverse, is it possible to make media player play videos in which audio may come out, not video, and media player may show a blank screen or default animation instead of video? I use Windows 7. Is it possible to play videos without displaying video in Windows Media Player 12

Comment: Is it obligatory to use Windows Media player or you just want any video player to play only the audio?

Comment: is there any other player?

Comment: Yes, check my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Download [VLC player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html).

Play whatever video you want > right click on the video > select video > video track > disable.

This will play only audio and will not consume resources for video.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of suggestions:

- Minimize Media Player - audio will play in the background
- Use [Miro Video Converter](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com) which can create an audio version (MP3) of your Video file

Comment: I think even minimized WMP will consume my GPU